# Phyloseq object, merge samples

Tags: phyloseq

I have a phyloseq file, in the OTU table there are several samples (i.e. SampleA, SampleB, SampleC...). I would like to merge the SampleA and SampleB samples into a single column), which statement should I use? Thank you

I searched online but there are instructions for merging two phyloseq files, not the individual samples

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.